# Display message based on JQuery UI Autosuggest Responses

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a form that is successfully displaying jquery UI autosuggest responses from a remote database. I would like to:

- Display a custom message based on the responses (e.g., you have 10 suggested items)
- Only allow the form to be submitted (validation) if there are no autosuggest responses.

I'm not sure the best way to do this. I'm exploring an AJAX validation as a seperate thing, but perhaps there is a way to customize the jquery UI code to display the message and validate the form.

I'm happy to provide any code, but for now it's just a simple jquery autosuggest function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `.data()` function on autocomplete for custom message display. The example shown on [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) documentation uses it to display custom data formats. You could append your suggestion count by doing something like:

```
$('#element').append(item.length + 'suggestions')
```

As for validation if there are no items you could enable/disable the submit button based on the response you get back or populate a hidden element with information as to what to do about submitting the form.

Comment: Thanks Austin. I'll check it out.